# Large percentage of app installs failing in large enterprise architecture

Tags: mdm

Please can anyone provide any troubleshooting tips or fixes (if you have fixed a similar issue before) regarding this issue below?
I do not have the full details yet - no architecture specific info / logs etc.

Initial information:
Fifty (50) percent of app installs fail, not of MobileIron itself, but of the enterprise apps they distribute via MobileIron. This is for a large enterprise with normal IT architecture with MobileIron MDM configuration.

Thank you for any help,
Mark Cooper
AAA Mobility Solutions

Comment: Your situation is too ambiguous. Are the 50% a specific device type? A specific platform? Specific device OS version? Are your devices toggling between multiple wireless networks?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need more details to get a good & helpful response on that.

- 50% of all installations fail: 50 % of the apps or 50 % of all installations of how many apps?
- Is the error related to the apps or to the devices or non of both?
- What version of MobileIron is in place?
- What error occurs in MobileIron and on the device in case of an error?
- Are the provided apps signed the right way with an enterprise In-house-distribution profile?
- Which is the source min SDK / iOS version of the apps and the target devices?
- Is the deployment method of the apps in MobileIron mandatory or optional?

If it is a large company: Do they have a support agreement with MI?